# Using Mod_Rewrite To Block Referrer Based On Domain Extenstion?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've been in web development for several years now (I'm a student web designer), and recently, I've begun to experiment with mod_rewrite for things like URL shortening.

I was wondering, is it possible to block a referrer by domain extension, instead of just by full site, etc.?

So, instead of

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} examplesite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

could you do

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

without the full domain name?

Thanks. I'm fairly knowledgeable about other web dev / hosting topics, but mod_rewrite is new to me and Google wasn't helping.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The right hand expression of the `RewriteCond` is simply a regular expression. The correct regular expression for *matching anything ending in ".com"* is:

```
\.com$
```

The `$` means "end of string".

Comment: It goes in the root directory's .htacess file, right? I tried the above with your $ addition as a test, and it didn't work. I'm wanting to use it to clean up .ru and other odd referrer domains cluttering my logs. Thanks.

Comment: Here's a screen shot of my .htaccess file currently, if that helps.

http://weatherworks.com/CaptureCode.PNG